# jQuery .html Is Changing The Font

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When attempting to use the jQuery .html function it appears to be changing the font of the div and I'm unsure why. Is there an error in my code?

Thank you in advance.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/_backend/forum/like_post.php',
    data: 'postID=' + postID,
    success: function(data){
        $(".btn-like-post[data-post-id='" + postID + "']").html( "<i class='fa fa-heart'> Liked (" + likedByNow + ")" );
        $(".btn-like-post[data-post-id='" + postID + "']").attr("class", "btn btn-dark-pink");
        $(".btn-like-post[data-post-id='" + postID + "']").attr("title", data );
    }
});
```

**EDIT**
Before: https://prnt.sc/g2r5bt
After: http://prntscr.com/g2r5jx

**EDIT**

CSS Code

```
.btn-dark-pink, .btn-dark-pink:hover, .btn-dark-pink:focus {
    background: #c43063;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;
}

.btn-pink, .btn-pink:hover, .btn-pink:focus {
    background: #f94a86;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;
}
```

Comment: `changing the font of the div`? what do you mean by this.? did your div have some data previously?

Comment: @AlivetoDie It changes the font, I'll edit the original post with some links to the pictures.

Comment: we can't tell without your CSS (your whole CSS, not just that little bit - we need a [mcve]). But maybe adding `.btn .btn-dark-pink` or `title="[whatever data is]"` will change the font via your CSS?

Comment: Try changing `$(".btn-like-post[data-post-id='" + postID + "']").attr("class", "btn btn-dark-pink");` to `$(".btn-like-post[data-post-id='" + postID + "']").addClass("btn btn-dark-pink");`

Comment: @ImArron we need all of the relevant CSS to reproduce the problem. See how to create a [mcve]

Comment: @ImArron  since you have `fa fa-heart` so these icons have their own font-style in there ttf,etc(4 files).that may cause

Comment: @AlivetoDie I don't think that is causing it because I have used this method previously on the site and it worked perfectly there.

Comment: could it be that `.html()` is replacing either a span or div that contains one of the `.btn-pink` class and is nested within `.btn-like-post[data-post-id='" + postID + "']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not closing your `<i>` element

it should look like

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/_backend/forum/like_post.php',
    data: 'postID=' + postID,
    success: function(data){
        $(".btn-like-post[data-post-id='" + postID + "']").html( "<i class='fa fa-heart'> Liked (" + likedByNow + ")</i>" );
        $(".btn-like-post[data-post-id='" + postID + "']").attr("class", "btn btn-dark-pink");
        $(".btn-like-post[data-post-id='" + postID + "']").attr("title", data );
    }
});
```

or better:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/_backend/forum/like_post.php',
    data: 'postID=' + postID,
    success: function(data) {

        $(".btn-like-post[data-post-id='"+ postID +"']")
          .html( "<i class='fa fa-heart'> Liked (" + likedByNow + ")</i>" )
          .attr({
            "class": "btn btn-dark-pink",
            "title": data
          });

    }
});
```

**Important Tip**
Don't use `postID` in the success like that... what I mean is: you could start a second request and the variable `postID` could change. Since the async nature of your request the earlier response could end up in the wrong element :) (the latterly referenced one)

instead, read the exact `postID` back from your response like `data.postID`

Comment: Thank you very much. Silly me!